# $f^{\prime}(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$, then $g(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

If $f$ is a defined and $\forall x>0, f^{\prime}(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$, then $g(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Note that 
$$g(x)=\frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{(x+1)-x}=\frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{1}$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f'(x)=0\implies \forall\varepsilon >0, \exists N>0 \space\space\text{s.t.}\space\space\space |f'(x)|<\varepsilon \space\space\forall x>N$$

$$\left| \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right| < \varepsilon \space\space\forall x>N$$

How can I somehow link the $h$ and $1$ together so that $g(x)$ is bounded by $\varepsilon$?

Comment: By $\forall x > 0, f' \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, do you mean $f'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: yes, i'll edit it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Mean Value Theorem.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Using MVT, there is some $c\in (0,1)$ so that $f'(x+c)=g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$. Then $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} g(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f'(x+c)=0$

Comment: That's right, pretty short.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)=0,
$$
there exists an $R=R(\varepsilon)>0$ such that 
$$
|f'(x)|\le \varepsilon \quad \forall x \ge R.
$$
For every $x \ge R$ we have
$$
\vert g(x)\vert=\vert f(x+1)-f(x)\vert=\left\vert\int_x^{x+1}f'(t)\,dt\right\vert \le \int_x^{x+1}|f'(t)|\,dt \le \int_x^{x+1}\varepsilon\,dt=\varepsilon,
$$
i.e. $\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)=0$.